# JSON sum values of a key where there are more keys with the same name PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am playing with some air quality data where each results contains at least 2 results. I know that I can limit the loop and get the data from the last entry only, but would have been very nice if I can actually sum the values of the same keys and divide the result by the number of entries, so I can get more precise value.[image]

A problem that I see there is that the key value for P1 and P2 are within the same array so no idea how to sum the two keys separately

The difference between the values in two sets of P1 and P2 keys is coming from the timestamp of the data.

Any idea how can I achieve that?

Here is the JSON data

```
[{"sensor":{"sensor_type":{"name":"SDS011","manufacturer":"Nova Fitness","id":14},"pin":"1","id":19770},"sensordatavalues":[{"value_type":"P1","value":"250.80","id":6323692330},{"value_type":"P2","value":"68.70","id":6323692332}],"location":{"country":"BG","latitude":"41.9460","altitude":"229.5","longitude":"25.5380","id":10044},"sampling_rate":null,"timestamp":"2019-02-26 14:02:34","id":2977869281},{"sensor":{"sensor_type":{"name":"SDS011","manufacturer":"Nova Fitness","id":14},"pin":"1","id":19770},"sensordatavalues":[{"value_type":"P1","value":"106.87","id":6323721400},{"value_type":"P2","value":"34.80","id":6323721402}],"location":{"country":"BG","latitude":"41.9460","altitude":"229.5","longitude":"25.5380","id":10044},"sampling_rate":null,"timestamp":"2019-02-26 14:05:04","id":2977883059}]
```

Comment: You want to sum the same Key values right ?

Comment: yes... P2 values and P1 Values and then divide them to number of results

Comment: Refer the answer and let me know 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54888438/json-sum-values-of-a-key-where-there-are-more-keys-with-the-same-name-php/54888788#54888788

Comment: is it working in your case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way, using 2 foreach loops and some variable variables.

```
$json = '[{"sensor":{"sensor_type":{"name":"SDS011","manufacturer":"Nova Fitness","id":14},"pin":"1","id":19770},"sensordatavalues":[{"value_type":"P1","value":"250.80","id":6323692330},{"value_type":"P2","value":"68.70","id":6323692332}],"location":{"country":"BG","latitude":"41.9460","altitude":"229.5","longitude":"25.5380","id":10044},"sampling_rate":null,"timestamp":"2019-02-26 14:02:34","id":2977869281},{"sensor":{"sensor_type":{"name":"SDS011","manufacturer":"Nova Fitness","id":14},"pin":"1","id":19770},"sensordatavalues":[{"value_type":"P1","value":"106.87","id":6323721400},{"value_type":"P2","value":"34.80","id":6323721402}],"location":{"country":"BG","latitude":"41.9460","altitude":"229.5","longitude":"25.5380","id":10044},"sampling_rate":null,"timestamp":"2019-02-26 14:05:04","id":2977883059}]';
$array = json_decode($json);

$P1 = 0;
$P2 = 0;
$P1C = 0;
$P2C = 0;
foreach ($array as $arr) {
    foreach ($arr->sensordatavalues as $obj) {
        ${$obj->value_type} += $obj->value;
        ${$obj->value_type.'C'}++;
    }
}
echo "P1 = $P1 and P2 = $P2\n"; 
echo "P1C = $P1C and P2C = $P2C\n"; 
echo "Last timestamp = " . $array[count($array)-1]->timestamp;
```

Output:

```
P1 = 357.67 and P2 = 103.5
P1C = 2 and P2C = 2
Last timestamp = 2019-02-26 14:05:04
```

Comment: Sound good, but how do you divide each sum on the number of results?

Comment: Ahh didnt see that in the comment. Check now I added a counter as well for each val

Comment: Yeap, it works great. How can I get the last timestamp?

Comment: There you go, the last timestamp

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$.each` method in jQuery and calculate the array values.

```js
var jsonURL = "https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5c755697f90f2c3f31aa1d6b";

var sumP1 = 0
var sumP2 = 0;

var countP1 = 0;
var countP2 = 0;

$.getJSON(jsonURL, function (result) {

    $.each(result, function (i, field) {

        var sensordatavalues = field.sensordatavalues;

        sensordatavalues.forEach(data => {

            if (data.value_type == "P1") {
                countP1++;
                sumP1 += Number(data.value);
            }

            if (data.value_type == "P2") {
                countP2++;
                sumP2 += Number(data.value);
            }

        });

    });

    console.log("sumP1: " + sumP1 / countP1);
    console.log("countP1: " + countP1);
    
    console.log("-------------------");
    
    console.log("sumP2: " + sumP2 / countP2);
    console.log("countP2: " + countP2);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yeap, that would work as well. But I needed a PHP way to do it. Nevertheless it is very good to have two different approaches to solve this case. Thanks.